# Bash grep pattern matching on a substring

Tags: bash, grep

I'm struggling a little bit with grep pattern matching. I thought ${d%?} would match on all but the last character, but it seems to be matching more aggressively than that.

```
dbs=$(${db_home}/bin/srvctl config | sort)
counter=1
for d in ${dbs[@]};do
  echo -e "dbs[${counter}] = ${d}"
  inst2[${d}]=$(sudo ${grid_home}/bin/crsctl stat res -w "((TYPE = ora.database.type) AND (LAST_SERVER = $(hostname -s)))" -f | grep ^USR_ORA_INST_NAME= | grep ${d%?})
  echo -e "inst2[${d}] = ${inst2[${d}]}"
```

I'd expect my output to be something like

```
dbs[1] = ope3u005
inst2[ope3u005] = USR_ORA_INST_NAME=ope3u0051
dbs[2] = ope3u006
inst2[ope3u006] = USR_ORA_INST_NAME=ope3u0061
```

But instead I'm getting

```
dbs[1] = ope3u005
inst2[ope3u005] = USR_ORA_INST_NAME=ope3u0051
USR_ORA_INST_NAME=ope3u0061
dbs[2] = ope3u006
inst2[ope3u006] = USR_ORA_INST_NAME=ope3u0051
USR_ORA_INST_NAME=ope3u0061
```

It's pretty clearly stripping off more than the last character for matching.

This isn't a use case for where we need to strip off the last character, but I'm trying to find a solution that works for this case as well as the cases where we do need to.

Comment: Please quote evaluations: `"${dbs[@]}"` and `"$(${db_home}/bin/srvctl config | sort)"` and the others.

Comment: Nice code, but not really relevant to your question. Please reduce to a simple case like `d=something; printf "str1\nstr2\n" | grep "${d%?}"`. We have no idea what is in your `$d` values. For futher examples on [mcve] as it applies to shell questions, search for the section "*How to turn a bad script into a good question" in this link : https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info . Good luck.

Comment: And I think stripping off the last char, where all others match, will still match unless you include the "end-of-string" anchor char `$`, so try `grep '${d%?}$'`. Note how `echo "matches" | grep 'matche'` **does match**, where as `echo "matches" | grep 'matche$'` doesn't. ;-). .... Good luck.

Comment: Also, putting `set -x` before the relevant section of the script will make bash print each command before executing it, which often makes it much clearer what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

If you strip the final character off "ope3u005" then obviously it's going to match both "ope30051" and "ope3u0061"